# Invalid CORS request Angular 2

Tags: angularjs-2.0

Buenas,

Ando algo desesperado porque soy incapaz de realizar un UPDATE mediante una API. La petición me da un error:

> 403 por Invalid CORS request.

Mi servicio:

```
private urlApi= 'http://localhost:8080/api';    
updateIt(id: string, lang: string, body: Object) {
        let bodyString = JSON.stringify(body);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Accept': '*/*' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this.http.post(this.copiesUrl + "/" + id + "/lang/" + lang, body, options)
                         .map((res:Response) => res.json())
                         .subscribe(
                            data => console.log('Success update ', data),
                            error => console.error('Error: ${error}')
                         );
    }
```

He probado ha poner una extensión de chrome para el tema de las CORS y en el campo "Intercepted URLs or URL patterns" he colocado `*://*/*`

Destacar que para hacer peticiones de consulta no estoy teniendo ningún problema.

Comment: Te diria algo 'tonto' que me paso recientemente, revisa la url que formas en total, a ver si estas doblando el numero de '/' y por eso me paso ami....

Comment: Ojalá pero está bien escrita jeje.

Comment: El backend lo has programado tu?

Comment: No, me ha venido dado. Aun que tengo acceso al código.

Comment: ¿Cómo estás manejando el uso del acceso autorizado?

Comment: Dónde estás ejecutando el backend? 
Frontend y backend tienen que ejecutarse en el mismo dominio para no tener problemas con CORS.
De hecho, está bien que sea así, porque sino en producción podés tener agujeros de seguridad, por eso no te recomiendo que habilites el backend para permitir `Cross Origin` requests salvo que eso sea una parte esencial de tu aplicación.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno soy nuevo en SO pero creo que si he encontrado la solución debo de escribir una respuesta a mi propia pregunta para dejar a los otros usuarios la solución al problema.

Finalmente y aun que he desencadenado otro error he conseguido solventar lo del tema de las CORS tocando la parte back de mi servicio. Es decir en la API. En mi caso el back está desarrollado en Java y Spring. Simplemente añadiendo la anotación de Spring `@CrossOrigin` se soluciona.

De forma que el servicio queda finalmente así:

```
 private urlApi= 'http://localhost:8080/api';    
updateIt(id: string, lang: string, body: Object) {
        let bodyString = JSON.stringify(body);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this.http.post(this.copiesUrl + "/" + id + "/lang/" + lang, body, options)
                         .map((res:Response) => res.json())
                         .subscribe(
                            data => console.log('Success update ', data),
                            error => console.error('Error: ${error}')
                         );
    }
```

Comment: Bueno parece que dicha solución no me ha servido, ya que al solucionar el problema de la petición POST (Debía de ser PUT ya que ese endpoint en back no soportaba POST) he vuelto a donde estaba jeje.

Comment: No soy experto en java pero revisa el siguiente enlace [Spring CORS](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/), si la solución no ha funcionado para tu problema deberías desmarcarla como correcta. Saludos

Comment: Hola Ricardo. Si lees la respuesta que me automarqué como correcta, edité para indicar la solución. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

creo que tu problema puede estar con el contenido que estás enviando. Si usas `JSON.stringify(body)`entiendo que te está generando un Json que es lo que estás enviando en la petición. Por lo tanto, el `Content-Type` debería ser `application/json`.

Prueba con esto a ver si se soluciona.

Comment: Así es como lo tenía en origen y tenía el mismo problema. De hecho ahora mismo lo tengo así con el `Content-Type` como `application/json` pero sigo con el mismo problema.

Comment: El backend en que está programado? Mira a ver si tiene alguna limitación de tipo cors.

Comment: El back está en Java. No se muy bien que tendría que buscar. En el controller no veo ninguna alusión al tema de las CORS.

Comment: Mira a ver algún filtro. Esto se suele implementar con algún filtro.

Comment: Estoy echando un ojo y en los archivos compilados si que estoy viendo alusiones a las CORS y demás. Seguiré echando un ojo a ver si saco algo en claro aun que no sé muy bien como voy a solucionarlo.

Comment: Ok, si necesitas algo aquí estamos.

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado. Gracias a todos. En el controlador del back en Spring había que añadir la etiqueta `@CrossOrigin` y listo, acepta peticiones externas.

Comment: Me alegro que lo hayas solucionado.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto debería ir como comentario pero no tengo los 50 puntos de reputación necesarios como para comentar, así que lo pongo por aquí.

He leído tu [otro problema](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52651/error-con-petici%C3%B3n-post-method-not-supported-request-method-post-not-suppor) y creo que te podría venir bien una herramienta que utilizo a diario para poder testar las API propias y de terceros. Se llama [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) y te permite realizar todo tipo de pruebas con APIs, muy util cuando tienes que investigar y probar como son o para testar la que estas haciendo.

Espero que te pueda servir.