# Error con petición POST: "Method not supported: Request method 'POST' not supported" 400

Tags: angularjs-2.0, post

Estoy tratando de consumir una API que solo acepta peticiones 'POST' para este caso y cuando realizo la petición me da un 400 con el error:

> "httpErrorMessage":"Bad Request","message":"Method not supported: Request method 'POST' not supported"

¿Alguna idea de dónde puede estar el problema?

Mi servicio.

```
 private urlApi= 'http://localhost:8080/api';    
updateIt(id: string, lang: string, body: Object) {
        let bodyString = JSON.stringify(body);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this.http.post(this.copiesUrl + "/" + id + "/lang/" + lang, body, options)
                         .map((res:Response) => res.json())
                         .subscribe(
                            data => console.log('Success update ', data),
                            error => console.error('Error: ${error}')
                         );
    }
```

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: El error está en el backend, que no soporta o admite peticiones de tipo POST para ese endpoint. ¿Que tecnología de backend estas usando? ¿Puedes añadir el código del servidor para ese endpoint?

Comment: Estoy utlizando Java para el back. Acabo de revisar y entre tu comentario y la respuesta he visto que lo que requiere es una petición del tipo put. Al invocar con put solvento el error aun que vuelvo al error anterior de las CORS. El que creía que había solventado aquí: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52151/invalid-cors-request-angular-2?noredirect=1#comment92412_52151

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo creo que el error está en que el endpoint al que estás invocando no soporta es método. Lo mismo si lo hace con un PUT o un GET, pero parece que POST no lo soporta.

Para estar seguro yo probaría a invocar directamente usando un cliente Rest y ver si te da el mismo error. Si es así, o estás invocando a la url que no debes o el servidor no está bien implementado.

Comment: Lo dicho arriba. Es eso, no soporta POST, si no PUT. Sin embargo he vuelto de nuevo al error de las CORS que creía ya solucionado aquí http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52151/invalid-cors-request-angular-2?noredirect=1#comment92412_52151

Comment: Si mi comentario te ha servido de ayuda te agradecería que lo marcases como útil.

Comment: Se me pasó hacerlo. Mira si no es molestia si puedes echarme una mano en el enlace que te paso ando un poco bloqueado con este tema...

Comment: Ahora le echo un ojo a ver si te puedo ayudar.